# variables from array POST dont get printed

Tags: php, vbscript, xmlhttprequest, wincc

The problem is:
I have a VBScript, which is run from the WinCCRuntime app (Siemens software). The script creates the MSXML2.XMLHTTP object and send data to a handler (written on PHP), which is run upon OpenServer 5.3.0.Premium (free web-server) 
on the same host (all the apps on a virtual machine). After script workiking I receive in VBS app readystate "4" and responsetext with correct data (PHP just prints out what it has received).
But these data dont get printed out on the page in the browser!!! 
(Echo prints nothing, print_r prints just ampty Array). 
The problem is the same when using GET and POST. When just go by link localhost:90/ajax1/handler.php?value=value 
everything is OK. 
I need to send data from WInCC app to WEB app. What is the promlem may be in? I had seen through:
[POST array not getting printed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901861/post-array-not-getting-printed)
But there's another matter.
Thank in advance.

This is the VBScript:

```
Sub OnLButtonDown(ByVal Item, ByVal Flags, ByVal x, ByVal y)                                                  

Dim xmlhttp
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

data1="hello"
xmlhttp.open "GET", "http://localhost:90/ajax1/handler.php?value="&data1, True
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", " *"
xmlhttp.send ""

Dim obj4 
Set obj4 = HMIRuntime.Screens("http").ScreenItems("Button2")
obj4.Text=xmlhttp.readyState

Dim obj3 
Set obj3 = HMIRuntime.Screens("http").ScreenItems("Button3")
obj3.Text=xmlhttp.responseText


End Sub
```

This is PHP script:

```
 <?php
    $value=$_GET['value'];
    echo $value."<br/>";
?>
```

[4 is readystate, hello
 is responsetext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnOU6.png)

Comment: `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` — This makes no sense. You are making a GET request, there is no body to describe the content type of.

Comment: `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", " *"` —  This makes no sense. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header, not a request header.

Answer (score 0):

You are making an **async** request. Program execution will continue and execute `obj4.Text=xmlhttp.readyState` **before** the ready state has reached 4 and the response processed.

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762767(v%3Dvs.85)):

> In Visual Basic, you need to write the following statement where
>   xmldoc is a variable and implements a subroutine called
>   xmldoc_onreadystatechange().
>
> ```
> Dim WithEvents xmldoc As DOMDocument30
> ```
>
> Example: See [Use OnReadyStateChange Property in Visual Basic and
>   Visual C/C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757030%28v%3Dvs.85%29).

Comment: @Victoria bear in mind those examples are for [tag:vb], not [tag:vbscript] the syntax is a bit different and some of the steps will be irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for help. I found out that my issues are satisfied with using of sync requests. And if it would be needed to print the data in web app without refreshing the page i should use js.